# PHP sorting an array of numbers

Tags: php, arrays

Why this array just return true ?, sort() doesnt work...

```
<?
for ($f = 0; $f < $numDados; $f++) {
$numRand = rand(1, 10);
$dataNum[] = $numRand;
}
$sortNum = sort($dataNum);
echo $sortNum;
?>
```

Comment: `sort` returns true on success and false on failure - it modifies the element passed to it by reference.

Comment: I see, so how could I do it? to order random numbers

Comment: Have a look at `$dataNum` after you called `sort`.

Comment: echo `$dataNum` - it will be sorted

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, I checked it, an it return an array of disorder numbers.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($dataNum);`? Also, see [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/boNUeE).

Comment: That's strange, because it works fine for me: http://codepad.org/nlEHxCrc. Maybe you are doing something different but are not showing it in your code?

Comment: general tip, working for all programming languages: if you think a core functionality is buggy – in 99.99999% of all cases it's not; it;s your code ;)

Comment: @Beat This varies by programming language. In PHP there's much less nines behind than in for example C.

Comment: @bwoebi I give you that ;) But if it's a core functionality since years, you can still be pretty sure it's you

Comment: @Beat I said this generally about PHP; not only this specific function ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTLM: http://php.net/sort

sort() does an in-place sort, and modifies the original array. it does not return a sorted copy.

```
$arr = array(....);
sort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

You also cannot `echo` an array. That'll just give you the literal text `Array`.

Comment: what does RTLM mean? I only know RTFM?

Comment: apparently rtfm is too "harsh" for this site, so I was asked to use "read the LINKED manual"

Comment: After shortly googling I didn't find RTLM... then write it out; or don't you want to be understood?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
$numDados=10;
for ($f = 0; $f < $numDados; $f++) {
$numRand = rand(1, 10);
$dataNum[] = $numRand;
}
$sortNum = sort($dataNum);

print_r($dataNum) ;
?>
```

Listen, sorted data are saved in the argument of 'sort()' function. and if sort() function execute successfully it returns 1 as true. hence $sortNum  contains 1 not the sorted array. sorted array is assigned in $dataNum. again you should use print_r() function instead of echo to print array. Here I add additional line   $numDados=10; to avoid error. if you have assigned a value in   $numDados in your code remove this line & you will get your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the manual: http://php.net/sort

> bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

It returns a bool about success and failure. And takes the array by reference.

So the array `$dataNum` will be sorted. And the return value you assign to `$sortNum` is `true` which is outputted as `1`.

Also you cannot print your array, use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see its contents.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has all sorts of weird (inconsistent) stuff like this.

```
$data = array(3,2,1);  // => Array (3, 2, 1)
sort($data);           // => true
print_r($data);        // => Array (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What's "dumb" about sorting arrays in-place?

Comment: saves a lot of memory... it would be dumb if it made a copy of my array.

Comment: reworded "dumb" to "inconsistent"

Answer (score 1):

It is already sorted (return true because sort() successfully sorted the array you passed), if you want look at it you can either do a var_dump($sortNum) or go through a loop and print everything out.

```
foreach($sortNum as $num)
echo $num;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   <?php
      for ($f = 0; $f < $numDados; $f++) {
      $numRand = rand(1, 10);
      $dataNum[] = $numRand;
     }
     sort($dataNum);
     echo "<pre/>"; print_r($dataNum);
   ?>
```